# PS4 HDMI Video Streaming via Upnp for access on other devices

Tags: raspbmc, hdmi

The Raspberry pi is a real awesome device and I have completed a couple of great projects which mainly revolves around my sweet media center complete with mood lighting. I am using a Raspberry Pi B+ with XBMC (not the OpenELEC version).

All of the above works beautifully so I decided it is time to attempt the next project in the line.

Planned Projects:

1. PS4 video streaming over UPNP (which this question is about)
2. Setting up ambilight for PS4 input via USB

The initial plan is to setup my PS4 to send the video to the raspberry pi so that I can access it through the RaspBMC menu (custom menu set up for PS4). Similar to the way that the live tv is accessed and then streamed to raspbmc but instead of cable I want an HDMI input so that I can send the video from the PS4 into the raspberry pi through the HDMI and the pi then displays the video as a stream in XBMC.

To extend to this, it would be great if this stream can be available to other devices via UPNP. I found a tutorial using the hdhomerun which does exactly what I want and can be accessed on any device on the network supporting UPNP. The problem is that the hdhomerun only does this for cable. I want exactly the same but with a video source which is the PS4 instead of cable.

View the video here to see what it's about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKpqmkpkyOA

I assume that in order to do this I will definitely need an additional piece of hardware (much like the hdhomerun but which can take HDMI input and send it over the network) but up until now I could not find a device to do this nor could I find any tutorial or articles on the net to help me accomplish this. Most of the hardware I found contains a transmitter and a receiver which takes the HDMI, converts it to the IP signal, sends it to the receiver and is in turn again converted to HDMI. This is not what I need.

So, onward to my solutions.

1. Finding a device to do the same as the hdhomerun but with an HDMI
   input instead of cable.
2. An alternative method by using a usb tv stick of some sort and show
   the video in XBMC similar to live tv with tvheadend.
3. Explore how to stream the PS4 video to a m3u playlist file and
   access that from XBMC. (I have not explored this option as this it
   the last resort).

Some sacrifices I am willing to make in the project:

1. The video does not HAVE to be HD. As long as it is good quality, I
   will be fairly happy although full HD is obviously preferred.
2. If it is not at all possible to stream the video via UPNP as the
   hdhomerun does, then I guess that I can let go of that dream.

The ultimate goal is this:

To access my PS4 straight from the XBMC menu without changing the input source of the television set.

Furthermore, the PS4 control is wireless so by getting the video to stream over UPNP, this will enable me to access the PS4 video and audio stream from any UPNP enabled device such as my tablet or smartphone. So when my wife hogs the living room tv watching her shows which I have absolutely no interest in, I can access my PS4 from any device in the house including tablets, smartphones, other television sets with raspbmc settopboxes. Even mobile devices running a distro of XBMC.

The final part to the question is if this will have an effect on the ambilight that I want to install at a later stage or will it make it easier in the end seeing as the video signal is already going into the pi?

This is the ambilight tutorial I will be following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRDAzJrfZiM

I do apologize for all the information in this question but it is not as simple as a one liner. This is also the reason why I am struggling to find help on Google.

Any pointers to articles, tutorials, hardware that I can use in this set up will be appreciated.